# PDF freezing my laptop

Tags: freeze, pdf, evince

I've tried to open this [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfok46sv4nomjdv/SEM5940-Slides-Handouts-Aulas_1_a_4.pdf?dl=0) (UPDATED) on Chrome, Evince and Zathura. All freeze my laptop. I've tried to compress the file using ghostscript, but it also freezes. I waited more than 1 hour and it just compress 4 pages. I'm wondering why this is happening, this PDF is less than 20 MB. Does anyone knows why this happening? I don't have a high end laptop, but it is not so bad.

[image: CPU USAGE]

Specs:

> CPU(s):              4
>
> Thread(s) per core:  2
>
> Core(s) per socket:  2
>
> Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
>
> RAM:                 16 GB

gs command cited above

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Comment: We cannot access this PDF as we cannot login. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you open the PDF in Windows? Have you tried `ocular` in Ubuntu?

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @user68186, I updated the link, now it is possible to download the file. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't try to open it on Windows, I don't have it installed. Yes, I've tried on ocular. OBS.: weirdly on Dropbox it opens normally, but if I try to print or if I download the file, my laptop can't open it. Very weird, actually.

Comment: @waltinator, actually my laptop has 16 GB of RAM. Running this command, I get: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1,6G         12G        662M        1,6G         12G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G. BTW, I've tried to open the PDF just running one program at time.

Comment: I had no problem downloading and opening the PDF with my 4GB chromebook converted to Ubuntu notebook. Your hardware is not the bottleneck here.

Comment: @user68186, did you open it on ocular?

Comment: No, I just used Evince, the default PDF viewer in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @user68186 Weird... I'm also use Evince, without any modifications. It opens large PDF (200+ MB) smoothly, but this PDF is struggling it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something wrong with the PDF document that you're unable to open. Google Docs has more advanced functionality at being able to open PDF documents than many locally installed PDF readers. Try uploading the PDF to Google Drive and open it. It will open by default in Google Docs. Once it is opened you can use Google Docs to convert the document from PDF to some other supported document format and then download it from Google Docs to your computer. This worked when I tried it with a problem document that I couldn't open on my computer.